# How to solve trouble with references in Xamarin project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I have a Xamarin project with Visual Studio 2017, how could I do to solve this trouble with this references that is appearing with exclamation mark?,[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHIft.jpg), because after with the NuGet packages restoration it continues appearing the same trouble with these references and also with the deletion of the packages folder content [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKWnj.jpg) in the project and doing the same process of restauration.
Any help or clue would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the obj, bin, clean then rebuild.
You can also remove them, rebuild, then re add through the nuget package manager.